# Removing unused variable causes shader not to draw anything

Tags: opengl-es, shader

I have a simple vertex and fragment shader that work and draw something. In the vertex shader I set the variable `fs_uv`, but I don't use it in the fragment shader. However if I comment out this line or change it to just `fs_uv = coord;` the shader stops drawing. What would cause this?

Vertex shader:

```
#version 300 es

precision mediump  float;
precision mediump  int;
precision lowp   sampler2D;
precision lowp   sampler2DArray;

in vec4 uv;

out vec2 fs_uv;
flat out uint draw_id;

uniform mat4 matrix;


void main() {
    vec2 coord = vec2(gl_VertexID >> 1, gl_VertexID & 1);

    fs_uv = uv.xy + coord * uv.zw;

    gl_Position = matrix * vec4(vec2(100.0f) * coord, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 300 es

precision mediump  float;
precision mediump  int;
precision lowp   sampler2D;
precision lowp   sampler2DArray;

in vec2 fs_uv;

out vec4 color;

void main() {
    color = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: I'm not removing either of those, I'm just remove the line where I set it. But I tried that too and it didn't work either.

Comment: [glGetProgramInfoLog](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glGetProgramInfoLog.xml)

Comment: There is no info, it compiles and link successfully

Comment: Looks like a platform bug - what GPU and driver version?

Comment: 1060 gtx, driver version 399.24

Comment: Did you try [glGetShaderInfoLog](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetShaderInfoLog.xhtml) as well?

Comment: My guess would be that when you make those changes, the driver is able to optimize out `in vec4 uv;`, so you're left with a vertex shader with no inputs at all. AFAIK, that's perfectly valid, but it's unusual enough that you might find a driver bug. Alternatively maybe you have other code that tries to bind to that vertex attribute and doesn't allow for the fact that the attribute might not necessarily exist. Do you check for errors after every GL call?

Comment: @Columbo drawing without explicit inputs isn't *that* uncommon.

Comment: @LJᛃ Fair point. I saw the GLES tag and assumed we were talking Android where driver quality is rather variable and there are difficulties with distributing driver fixes to end-users. I see from the comments that it's actually an NVidia laptop GPU, so I'd expect attribute-less rendering to be well handled.